# SVG file excessive white space

Tags: svg

there are some answers here but it's not helping me, I have massive excessive white space. I am using Adobe Illustrator CS4. I think I have all the coordinates set properly but I'm a beginner.

Here is the file:
https://chordsandguitar.com/glossary-3.svg

Any help is definitely appreciated.

Thanks,

Jacques

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can just [change the size of the artboard](https://imgur.com/Mn5KRIB) using the Artboard tool. It's too big.

Comment: Billy, thank you so much, this is better. But I'm still getting white space to the right and below, it might be the viewport; I'm going to have to study up on this.

Comment: Are you trying to centre it in the browser?  If so, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281951/how-to-position-my-svg-image-to-the-center-of-browser) or possibly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639383/how-do-i-center-an-svg-in-a-div)

Comment: Ah, yes I see, thanks.